# Goal: Writing Effective Unit Tests to Ensure a Datetime Conversion To/From Local-UTC Works

Tags: python, datetime, unit-testing

As the title lists, I am trying to write an effective unittest suite to ensure that the function that converts a date to UTC from local or vice-versa is doing as planned. But it seems hard because time zones/changes vary a lot so what level of coverage suffices?

Here is my code thus far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pendulum

from datetime import datetime
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder as tzf

from ...common.constants.literals import TimeZoneInputs


class DateParser(object):
    """object to store date parameters and modify dataframe date to appropriate timezone"""

    def __init__(
        self,
        datetime_format: str,
        date_field: str,
        input_timezone: str,
        df: pd.DataFrame,
        lon_lat_columns: tuple,
    ):
        self.format = datetime_format
        self.input_timezone = input_timezone

        self.date_field = date_field
        self.lon = lon_lat_columns[0]
        self.lat = lon_lat_columns[1]
        self.tzf = tzf()  # timezone finder
        self.today = pendulum.now()
        self.today_utc = self.today.in_timezone('UTC')
        self.df_temp = pd.DataFrame(df[(df[self.lon].isna()) | (df[self.lat].isna())])
        self.df = self.parse_date(
            pd.DataFrame(df[(df[self.lon].notna()) & (df[self.lat].notna())])
        )

    def parse_date(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:

        df[self.date_field] = pd.to_datetime(df[self.date_field], format=self.format)

        (
            df[bc.TZ_OFFSET],
            df[bc.TZ_NAME],
        ) = self.get_offset_vec(df[self.lon].astype(float), df[self.lat].astype(float))
        return pd.concat([df, self.df_temp], axis=0)

    def get_offset_and_tz(self, lng, lat):
        """
        returns a location's time zone offset from UTC in minutes.
        """
        tz_at = self.tzf.timezone_at(lng=lng, lat=lat)
        tz_target = pendulum.timezone(tz_at)
        if tz_target is None:
            return None, None
        today_target = pendulum.instance(self.today).in_tz(tz_at)  

        # Difference in timezone offsets, which specifies the +/- number of seconds offset from UTC:
        return (self.today_utc.offset - today_target.offset ) / 3600, tz_at

    def get_offset_vec(self, lng, lat):
        return np.vectorize(self.get_offset_and_tz, cache=True)(lng, lat)

    def add_utc(self, utc_col: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
        # use timezone finder to convert timezone from local_tz to utc
        if self.input_timezone == TimeZoneInputs.LOCAL:
            self.df[utc_col] = self.df[self.date_field] + pd.to_timedelta(
                self.df[bc.TZ_OFFSET], unit="h"
            )
        else:
            self.df[utc_col] = self.df[self.date_field]
        return self.df

    def add_local_time(self, local_tz_col) -> pd.DataFrame:
        # use timezone finder to convert timezone from utc to local_tz
        if self.input_timezone == TimeZoneInputs.UTC:
            self.df[local_tz_col] = self.df[self.date_field] - pd.to_timedelta(
                self.df[bc.TZ_OFFSET], unit="h"
            )
        else:
            self.df[local_tz_col] = self.df[self.date_field]
        return self.df
```

**Tests**

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd


from src.transform.common.date_parser import (
   DateParser,
    TimeZoneInputs
)


class TestDateParser(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Unit tests for the DateParser class.
    """

    def setUp(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame({
            'date_field': [pd.Timestamp('2023-05-08 00:00:00')],
            'lon': [-74.0060],  # longitude for NYC
            'lat': [40.7128]  # latitude for NYC
        })
        self.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        self.date_field = 'date_field'
        self.input_timezone = TimeZoneInputs.UTC
        self.lon_lat_columns = ('lon', 'lat')

    def test_add_utc(self):
        parser = DateParser(self.datetime_format, self.date_field, self.input_timezone, self.df, self.lon_lat_columns)
        df_with_utc = parser.add_utc('utc_col')
        self.assertIn('utc_col', df_with_utc.columns)

    def test_add_local_time(self):
        parser = DateParser(self.datetime_format, self.date_field, self.input_timezone, self.df, self.lon_lat_columns)
        df_with_local_time = parser.add_local_time('local_time_col')
        self.assertIn('local_time_col', df_with_local_time.columns)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

A test suite is an opportunity to clarify what the
observable behavior of a Public API is intended to be.
The current suite isn't quite there, yet.

## attribute count

Each `DateParser` object has ten attributes.
That seems like a lot.
Do we *really* need all of them?

Worse, they're all public.
Make ones like `self._tzf` private, please.
Some of those methods look like they should be `_private` helpers, also.

It's fine for a unit test to reach in and frob a `_private`
attribute, but I wouldn't expect target code in an application
to be calling the timezone finder.

Also, this isn't python2, please turn `class DateParser(object):`
into a simple `class DateParser:`

## missing review context

You didn't explain what `bc` means, but that's OK.

## comments lie!

```
    def get_offset_and_tz( ... ):
        """
        returns a location's time zone offset from utc in MINUTES.
        """
        ...  
        # Difference ... which specifies the +/- number of SECONDS offset from utc:
        return (self.today_utc.offset - today_target.offset ) / 3600, tz_at
```

We're multiplying by an `HOURS_PER_SECOND = 1/3600`
[conversion factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_units#Factor%E2%80%93label_method),
so the returned value has units of HOURS.

## test behavior that users care about

I don't understand how asking for a column to be added,
and then verifying the column exists,
is of interest to an end user.

```
    def test_add_utc(self):
        ...
        self.assertIn('utc_col', df_with_utc.columns)

    def test_add_local_time(self):
        ...
        self.assertIn('local_time_col', df_with_local_time.columns)
```

(It would suffice to ask if that name is `in df_with_utc` --
the `.columns` attribute will implicitly be queried.)

Surely the particular `str` display time is what's of interest, right?
So test *that*!

## test code is simple code

The `today` logic is fine, feel free to leave that in.
And NYC is a nice place, leave it in if you like.
But let's examine some edge cases.

Choose three "nearby" and "interesting" cities:

- Los Angeles
- Denver
- [Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States#Arizona)

Choose a pair of times on either side of a DST divide:

- 2024-03-10T12:30
- 2024-03-10T03:30

Now just write 6 or 12 extremely simple `self.assertEqual()`'s.
Verify the `str` UTC form and the local form work out to what you expect,
before and after the DST change.
In two cities we expect to see an hour delta,
while in Phoenix we should observe no DST change at all.

Consider doing this for November 3rd, as well.

## tests prevent regressions

Imagine the target code had already been released
into production, and had already produced bug report(s)
last November 5th.
End users would be complaining that a displayed time didn't
match what their wristwatch was saying, right?
So we would open a ticket and a feature branch to fix the bug,
and the first step would be reproducing the bug.
Having created a Red (failing) unit test,
we then fix the target code to turn it Green,
and in subsequent months we keep re-running that test
to verify no code maintenance regresses it back to Red.

That's a test that adds value.

Now pretend things played out that way last November,
and set your self the task right now of authoring
similar tests.
They will start out Green.
And we add them to the codebase
so CI/CD will keep verifying that they stay Green.

---

Here is an example of a "dirt simple" unit test
that demonstrates user-visible DST behavior.
For your code, if you trust the libraries work fine,
a one-liner which verifies a (lat, long) got turned
into `"America/Denver"` might suffice.

```
import datetime as dt
import unittest

from dateutil.tz import gettz


class TzTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_verify_dst_behavior(self):
        lax = gettz("America/Los_Angeles")
        den = gettz("America/Denver")
        phx = gettz("America/Phoenix")

        # half-hour before start of any DST transitions, PHX matches DEN
        t1 = dt.datetime.fromisoformat("2024-03-10T07:30Z")
        self.assertEqual("2024-03-10 07:30:00+00:00", str(t1))
        self.assertEqual("2024-03-10 00:30:00-07:00", str(t1.astimezone(den)))
        self.assertEqual("2024-03-10 00:30:00-07:00", str(t1.astimezone(phx)))
        self.assertEqual("2024-03-09 23:30:00-08:00", str(t1.astimezone(lax)))

        # after all DST transitions have happened, PHX matches LAX
        t2 = t1 + dt.timedelta(hours=3)
        self.assertEqual("2024-03-10 10:30:00+00:00", str(t2))
        self.assertEqual("2024-03-10 04:30:00-06:00", str(t2.astimezone(den)))
        self.assertEqual("2024-03-10 03:30:00-07:00", str(t2.astimezone(phx)))
        self.assertEqual("2024-03-10 03:30:00-07:00", str(t2.astimezone(lax)))
```

Comment: thank you -- what do you mean by "today" logic?

Comment: You use a global variable, the wallclock, when you consult `.now()`. Usually we try to avoid such things in unit tests, in the interest of reproducibility. But in this case it seems to work out fine.

Comment: thank you, as well for example test - is this what you meant? I am getting in an error, but conceptually did I translate your spec into code correct? It feels like I am just comparing more abstracted code to less abstracted code, so not sure if it is just vanity?

# UTC column assertions
    utc_col_name = f'{city}_utc_col'
    df_with_utc = parser.add_utc(utc_col_name)
    assert df_with_utc[utc_col_name][0].tz_localize('UTC') == pd.Timestamp('2024-03-10 12:30:00', tz='UTC')
    assert df_with_utc[utc_col_name][1].tz_localize('UTC') == pd.Timestamp('2024-03-10 03:30:00', tz='UTC')

Answer (score 1):

Time and date is a deeply gnarly subject, but parsing and comparing can be fairly straighforward.

Also note your above code is very slow because it re-initializes the 'tzf' object repeatedly. That could be avoided by using a static instance, like this:

```
class DateParser:
    """object to store date parameters and modify dataframe date to appropriate timezone"""
    # static data members
    static_tzf = tzf()  # timezone finder
```

But otherwise, testing is a process of supplying data and checking the answers are as expected. There's be strange cases of datelines, ship-board time adjustments, leapseconds and so on, but maybe your needs are simple.

```
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects
from datetime import timedelta
# https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/
from dateutil import parser
# https://pypi.org/project/pytz/
import pytz

class DTDiff:

    def zoneparse(dtstr, zonestr):
        naivedt = parser.parse(dtstr)
        zn = pytz.timezone(zonestr)
        awaredt = zn.localize(naivedt)
        return awaredt

    def dotest_offs(dstr1, dstr2, diff):
        # test with zone as offset in string
        td = parser.parse(dstr1) - parser.parse(dstr2)
        print("test with zone as offset : " + ('Ok' if (td == diff) else 'Fail'))

    def dotest_iana(dstr1, tzstr1, dstr2, tzstr2, diff):
        # test with zone as IANA name
        td = DTDiff.zoneparse(dstr1, tzstr1) - DTDiff.zoneparse(dstr2, tzstr2)
        print("test with zone as zone-name : " + ('Ok' if (td == diff) else 'Fail'))

    def runtests():
        # time 1
        time1 = '2020-01-01 18:00:00'
        zone1off = '-0700'
        zone1name = 'America/Los_Angeles'
        # time 2
        time2 = '2020-01-01 18:20:00'
        zone2off = '+0200'
        zone2name = 'Europe/Tirane'
        # timedelta : https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects
        td = timedelta(seconds=31200)

        # zone offset: should work
        DTDiff.dotest_offs(time1+' '+zone1off, time2+' '+zone2off, td)
        # zone offset: should fail
        try:
            DTDiff.dotest_offs(time1, time2+' '+zone2off, td)
            print('expected TypeError : Fail')
        except TypeError:
            print('expected TypeError (mixed naive and aware datetimes) : Ok')

        # IANA zone name: should work
        DTDiff.dotest_iana(time1, zone1name, time2, zone2name, td)
        # IANA zone name: should fail
        try:
            DTDiff.dotest_iana(time1, zone1name, time2, None, td)
            print('expected UnknownTimeZoneError : Fail')
        except pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError:
            print('expected UnknownTimeZoneError : Ok')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DTDiff.runtests()
```